# How many kg of air escape from the Quest airlock during one EVA?

Tags: iss, airlock, quest-joint-airlock

Do they have a system that pumps the air out or does it just let it out?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I haven't found a reference giving the number, but we can make a back of the envelope approximation.

Page 49 of  [The International Space Station - Operating an Outpost in the New Frontier](https://www.nasa.gov/sites/default/files/atoms/files/iss-operating_an_outpost-tagged.pdf) reminds us that the crewlock on the ISS is the same volume as the Shuttle Orbiter airlock.

From work experience as a Shuttle Systems instructor, I know

- Volume of empty airlock ~ 185 cubic feet
  [image]
- Volume of suited crewmember ~ 10 cubic feet
  [image]
- So the air volume in airlock with 2 suited crewmembers present ~ 165 cubic feet

(If you are wondering about the 228 cubic feet in the table vs the 185 cubic feet in the diagram, the difference is the 43 cubic feet of the tunnel extension, which the ISS crewlock doesn't have)

[image]

Assuming normal conditions of 1 atm and 72 deg F the ideal gas law gives us ~ 12 lbm or 5.4 kg of air in the airlock at the start of the depress.

This answer [How Is The Quest Joint Airlock Operated?](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/33149/how-is-the-quest-joint-airlock-operated/33168#33168) tells us that the ISS airlock depress pump scavenges ~ 10 psi of the air. So ~ (5/15) * 5.4 kg is lost or in round numbers, 2 kg.

(Source of images: SMS Systems Console Handbook)

Comment: It is surprising and lamentable that official spaceflight documents use cubic feet.

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica the shuttle was designed in the 1970s. The only space program to land people on the Moon to date used English units. I'm kind of tired of people complaining about it. Use some historical perspective. At this point it's just units-virtue-signaling, we get it.

Comment: Point taken ;-).

Comment: Here in that document on page 143 they write that only 10% of the gas will be lost. What causes such a difference? https://ntrs.nasa.gov/api/citations/20180001338/downloads/20180001338.pdf

Comment: @SaturnV the scavenge pump is turned back on for the depress from 5 psi for some more time, I didn't account for that in this estimation. Among other things. If you found a real source, that's much better than this. I encourage you to write an answer and reference it.

Comment: You write that you are a Shuttle Systems instructor. I am interested in environmental control systems. Do you know any engineers who worked on ECS? I would be interested in any experiences.

Comment: I didn't 'work on' the systems but I helped train the crew and flight controllers on the shuttle ECLSS. The flight controllers monitored the systems and advised the crew on how to configure them. The techs at KSC turned the wrenches on the systems in the hangar. Everything was designed and built before my time.

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metrication_in_the_United_States#20th_century is relevant and interesting

Comment: @OrganicMarble: How long would it take to pump down to 5psi?  If a crew would have nothing useful to do while waiting for air to be pumped before an EVA, losing 1/3 of the air might be better than wasting more time.  If, however, the crew had useful duties that could be performed while they were in the airlock and it was being pumped, there might be no reason not to scavenge more of the air.

Comment: @supercat per the procedure linked in the other answer,the crew opens the manual depress valve to blow down from 5 psi to 0. They let the pump run until 2 psi just to get whatever they can.  The crew can't really do anything in the airlock, it's pretty small and they are jammed in there waiting to go out.